# Generating all possible rgb colors

Tags: python, colors

It seems like it'd be much simpler than it is, but what can be done to generate all 16,777,255 rgb colors with python?

Comment: You probably want to do something else, maybe a color picker ? That is not how it is done. Also, there is no reason to think RGB is restricted to 8 bits per channel (thus limiting to 2^24 colors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colors are usually represented as hexadecimal numbers which are actually just integers. So a simple loop from 0 to 16,777,215 (0xFFFFFF) would be enough to generate all 24 bit RGB colors.

In python 2.x, you can do:

```
allcolors = range(0xFFFFFF+1):
```

Comment: `list(range(...))` would be superior here (in 3.x. In 2.x, `range()` already returns a list). No need to make a loop just to make a list.

Answer (score 7):

8-bit RGB values are 3-tuples of numbers 0..255. You can generate them all conveniently using the cartesian product function from itertools.

```
itertools.product(xrange(256), repeat=3)
```