# all possible hex codes

Tags: python, colors, hex, rgb

I'm very new to coding so sorry for any possible idiot questions

I'm doing a project in which I need to code of every possible hex value.
I do know that there are more than 16 million values (16777215 to be exact) and I have also tried to follow the instructions here ( [Generating all possible rgb colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106917/generating-all-possible-rgb-colors) ) but it "only" gives me the numbers from 1 to 16777215 and not the proper values.

I'm not sure if this is possible but I would deeply appreciate any help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's a "proper value"? Can you give an example?

Comment: You could use format strings `'{:x}'.format(8191)` ->
`'1fff'`.

Comment: First, the code there should also have given you 0. Second, the integers from 0 to 16777215 are a perfectly valid, common representation of 24-bit color values, and in fact, they're quite likely the representation you need.

Answer (score 3):

The decimal value for, say, white is 16777215. The hexadecimal representation of that number is 0xFFFFFF. To print the hex representation of a number in Python, use `hex`.

```
>>> rgb = 16777215
>>> hex(rgb)
'0xFFFFFF'
```

You could also use the `%x` or `%X` format.

```
>>> rgb = 16777215
>>> print('%06x' % rgb)
ffffff
>>> print('%06X' % rgb)
FFFFFF
```